# Preserve whitespaces in DT table

Tags: r, dt

I have created a data frame which has multiple spaces in the first row name ("Number   1"). However when created DT table white spaces have been removed. I am wondering if there is any way to preserve these? Is there anything similar to check.names in DT?

```
table <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 10 , nrow = 11, 
                           dimnames=list(c("Number       1", seq(2,11,1)), seq(0,9,1))), 
                    check.names=FALSE)


datatable(table,
          rownames=TRUE,
          class="compact",
          fillContainer = F,
          options =list(dom = "t",
                        ordering = F,
                        autoWidth = TRUE)) %>%
  formatStyle(columns=0,
              textAlign="right")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the spaces in the rownames by `&nbsp` and add `escape = FALSE`:

```r
library(DT)

table <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 10 , nrow = 11, 
                           dimnames=list(c("Number       1", seq(2,11,1)), seq(0,9,1))), 
                    check.names=FALSE)
rownames(table) <- gsub(' ', '&nbsp', rownames(table))
DT::datatable(table, rownames=TRUE, class="compact", fillContainer = FALSE,
              escape = FALSE, 
              options =list (dom = "t", ordering = FALSE, autoWidth = TRUE)) %>%
    formatStyle(columns=0,
                textAlign="right")
```

see https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/215

output:

[image: table]